# Evaluate the limits of this function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let $v\,\epsilon\,[0,\,\overline{v}]$ be a random variable with a pdf $\varphi(\cdot)$. Define the function $F(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\,\epsilon\,(0,\,q)$,

$F(\alpha\,; D,\,q) = \int\limits^{d_c}_{0} \frac{1-q}{(1-\pi)^2}\frac{1}{D-v}\bigg(v(\frac{1+\pi}{1-\pi})-D\bigg)\varphi(v)dv$ where, $d_c = D(1-\alpha/q),\,\pi= \frac{\alpha D}{D-v}$, and $D\,\epsilon\,(0,\,\overline{v}),\, q\,\epsilon\,(0,\,1)$ are constants.

Do the limits $\lim_{\alpha\,\rightarrow\,0}F(\alpha)$ and $\lim_{\alpha\,\rightarrow\,q}F(\alpha)$ exist?

The underlying confusion that I have is under what conditions the limit of an integral w.r.t to a parameter exist, especially when the bounds of that integral also vary with the parameter?

Comment: As the question says, the parameters are constants, so you don't need to worry about them other than to possibly make use of their known bounds.

Comment: @ConMan so the limits exist and can be found by substituting the bounds for $\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, at least in theory.